# PrimeNg multiselect returning empty values

Tags: angular, primeng

I have this json that i get through an API call :

```
 [
  {
    "CategoryID": "1",
    "CategoryName": "cat1",
    "DocDescription": "cat1 description",
    "Indexes": [
      {
        "IndexID": "1",
        "IndexName": "id1name",
      },
      {
        "IndexID": "2",
        "IndexName": "id2name",
      },
      {
        "IndexID": "3",
        "IndexName": "id3name",
      }..
    ]
  }... 
]
```

I have declared the following variables :

```
categoriesResponseModel: CategoriesResponseModel;
categories: CategoryModel[] = [];
category: CategoryModel;
@Output()  selectedCategories =  new EventEmitter<CategoryModel[]>();
```

My call is the following :

```
private getCategories(): void {
  const response = this.apiService.getCategories().subscribe(
    (res) => {
      this.categoriesResponseModel = JSON.parse(res);
      for (const category of this.categoriesResponseModel.CATEGORIES) {
        this.categories.push(category);
      }
    },
    (err) => { console.log(err.message); },
    () => { console.log('Completed - Categories pushed'); }
  );
}
```

I try to display the result in an multiselect input with PrimeNg :

```
<p-multiSelect
  [options]="categories"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
  [filter]="true"
  [showTransitionOptions]="'50ms'"
  [hideTransitionOptions]="'50ms'"
>
</p-multiSelect>
```

I do display the categories using {{ categories | json }} in my template, I also have the multiselect displaying but it's not working correctly

[image]

Comment: consider adding optionLabel="IndexName" to your multiselect.
<p-multiSelect
  [options]="categories"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
  [filter]="true"
  [showTransitionOptions]="'50ms'"
  [hideTransitionOptions]="'50ms'"
[optionLabel]="'IndexName'"
>
</p-multiSelect>

Comment: It works only if I hard code my object ... I'll try to find out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hassan and PrimeNg documentation, it works perfectly.
I finally used the templated version :

```
<p-multiSelect
  [options]="categories"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedCategories"
  defaultLabel="Select a Category"
  optionLabel="CategoryName"
  class="multiselect-custom">
  <ng-template let-value pTemplate="selectedItems">
    <div class="itemlist itemlist-value" *ngFor="let option of selectedCategories">
      <div>{{option.CategoryName }}</div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!selectedCategories || selectedCategories.length === 0" class="country-placeholder">
      Select categories
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template let-category pTemplate="item">
    <div class="itemlist">
      <div>{{category.value.CategoryName }}</div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>
```

I met the same issue because I was trying to display  :

```
{{category.CategoryName }}
```

instead of

```
{{category.value.CategoryName }}
```